# Can one prove a connection between the order of the polynomials in a differential equation and the roots of the characteristic equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am teaching myself how to solve differential equations and have now gone through a section on non-homogeneous second order linear equations. I have the following problem to solve, which I have been stuck on for a few days:

Assume that the differential equation $ y''+ay'+by=p(x)e^{kx}$ has a solution $q(x)e^{kx}$, where both $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are polynomials.
Prove the following:

1. If *k* is not a root of the characteristic equation, then the degree of *q* equals the degree of *p*
2. If *k* is a simple root of the characteristic equation, then the degree of *q* is one higher than the degree of *p*
3. If *k* is a double root of the characteristic equation, then the degree of *q* is two higher than the degree of *p*

I have tried substituding *y* for a guessed solution of the form $y=ze^{kx}$ where *z* is a polynomial and expanded the differential equation, but this has brought me nowhere. I honestly have no idea how to go forward with this. Can anyone think of a strategy?

Comment: 3)If k is a double root of the characteristic equation, then the order of p is two higher than the order of q................It should be the opposite.

Comment: In English, the standard term for "single root" is "simple root" and the standard term for "the order of $p$" (a polynomial) is "the degree of $p$".

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful. English is not my mothertongue and I am reading mathematics texts in Icelandic. Translating and finding the correct terms in English is a pain in the neck! Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y''+ay'+by=p(x)e^{kx}$$
**Hint:**

Substitute $y=q(x)e^{kx}$ in the original DE and regroup terms:
$$q''(x)+q'(x)\color {green}{(a+2k)}+q(x)\color {red}{(k^2+ak+b)}=p(x)$$
Note that the characteristic polynomial for the homogeneous DE is
$$y''+ay'+by=0$$
$$\implies r^2+ar+b=0$$
So if $k$ is a simple root then the terms in red are zero....what can you deduce for the degree of $q(x)$?
So if $k$ is a double root then the terms in green and red are zero....what can you deduce for the degree of $q(x)$?

Comment: Thanks for this. This pushed me in the right direction and the problem is now solved!

Comment: You're welcome  @ArnórBjarkiSvarfdal